# JavaScript window.onsubmit event.keyCode undefined

Tags: javascript

A client's employees I'm migrating away from Microsoft Access have been used to pressing `Enter` to `Tab` through form fields, an odd scenario though a scenario nonetheless. So I need to `preventDefault` on the `window.onsubmit` event, only `event.keyCode` isn't defined!

```
window.onsubmit = function(event)
{
 alert('event.keyCode = '+event.keyCode);
}
```

Here is the list of what methods, objects and properties that JavaScript returns for on the `event` parameter...

```
window.onsubmit.event.isTrusted
window.onsubmit.event.stopPropagation
window.onsubmit.event.stopImmediatePropagation
window.onsubmit.event.preventDefault
window.onsubmit.event.initEvent
window.onsubmit.event.getPreventDefault
window.onsubmit.event.type
window.onsubmit.event.target
window.onsubmit.event.currentTarget
window.onsubmit.event.eventPhase
window.onsubmit.event.bubbles
window.onsubmit.event.cancelable
window.onsubmit.event.defaultPrevented
window.onsubmit.event.timeStamp
window.onsubmit.event.originalTarget
window.onsubmit.event.explicitOriginalTarget
window.onsubmit.event.NONE
window.onsubmit.event.CAPTURING_PHASE
window.onsubmit.event.AT_TARGET
window.onsubmit.event.BUBBLING_PHASE
window.onsubmit.event.ALT_MASK
window.onsubmit.event.CONTROL_MASK
window.onsubmit.event.SHIFT_MASK
window.onsubmit.event.META_MASK
```

Comment: I should note that this is only a temporary solution until I have time to make the `Enter` key emulate the `Tab` key though only in forms, if it is still desired by the client.

Comment: Um, why are you listening to submit on the window and not the form?

Comment: @epascarello Because this applies to their *entire* intranet website, not just a single form.

Comment: But how does enter submit a page without a form?

Comment: @epascarello The object `window.onsubmit` applies to *all* forms when being submitted, all events have a `window.on`-xyz equivalent, like `window.onclick`. This is exceptionally useful because in many circumstances (such as this Q/A) it is necessary to combine two `window` global events to achieve something a single `window` global event can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Except for ondemand JavaScript my work involves (server compiled) `index.js` and `events.js`, all the `window.onevent` handlers are stored in `events.js` file. While it is apparently not directly possible it is still *indirectly* possible to prevent the `Enter` key from submitting the form. Additionally it seems the `keypress` event triggers the `click` event, probably for accessibility purposes. I've also included a work-around to determine which event happened first; each browser triggers the `click` event between 0~20ms after the `keypress` event is triggered and so I've taken that in to consideration to ensure that the range is 0~50ms. Here are the browser response times between event triggers and the code...

**Chrome** 39.0

**Firefox 31.0** ESR: 18~20ms

**IE 11**: 2~4ms

**Opera 12.1**: 0ms

```
var option = new function() {this.name = '';}


window.onclick = function(event)
{
 option.clickDate = new Date().getTime();
}


window.onkeypress = function(event)
{
 option.keyCode = event.keyCode;
 option.keyCodeDate = new Date().getTime();
}


window.onsubmit = function(event)
{
 if (option.keyCodeDate && option.clickDate && 
 ((option.clickDate - option.keyCodeDate)>=0 && 
 (option.clickDate - option.keyCodeDate)<51) && 
 option.keyCode==13) {event.preventDefault();}
 {
  event.preventDefault();
 }
}
```